# Allow certain user-agents that starts with x to a folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

my bucket got this folder called `public/` and I wonder if there's a chance to only allow User-Agent headers that starts with a certain string, for example, anyone with a user agent that starts with "Hello" should be able to access the files inside the folder. (example: `User-Agent: "HelloSDK_PC...... *this continues*"`)

Clients who do not match this criteria should receive "Access Denied"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can attach the following bucket policy to your S3 bucket.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket-Name/public/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:UserAgent": "Hello*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You're the best.